# partial update in apk instead of downloading full apk again

Tags: android, apk

I have one app published in app store now every time when i am updating small change to the app should i have to generate new apk and update it to google play store? 
i wanted to make my app like hostar,youtube so that only updates will be downloaded instead of whole apk to download.
eg. my apk size is 30MB then i have updated small change say for example 2kb update so instead of downloading whole apk again my app users can download only 2kb update.
Hope you got my question.

Comment: This is handled by Google itself. You don't have to handle  this in your code end. Just follow the normal way generate and update the apk to play store. Play store will serve only the portion which needs to be updated to users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Play Store does that for you. How, I don't know, but if you try to upload a new version, you will see that the size displayed while download is not the same as the full app if you doing an update. I believe most of the time, the compiled part is always downloaded and maybe the resources, there is a diff, so you just download the ones you don't have already.

Here's a blog post with more details: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/saving-data-reducing-the-size-of-app-updates-by-65-percent.html